# SU tag merge request: [install] related

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

Can the following tag groups on SuperUser be merged?

- [**install**] (x239), [**installation**] (x393),
  [**installing**] (x4), [**installed**] (x1).
- [**installer**] (x48), [**installers**] (x2).

Comment: Merged into which tag?

Comment: The decision is moderator's but IMO, into the first one in each group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is complete, and appropriate synonyms are in place.